# Mass In App Purchase through application loader

Tags: ios, iphone, in-app-purchase, app-store-connect, application-loader

i was uploading my apps on itunes connect. For in app purchase i am using mass import template for uploading IAP but now i am getting error

> ERROR ITMS-5103: "Default product interval not supplied (in-app purchase with product_id='com.mclegacy.megacasino3.combo3'). For a new in-app-purchase, a default product interval must be supplied:  no start date (or start date of today or earlier) and no end date." at Software/Soft

Answer (score 8):

[image]        This error is mainly due to the mismatch of time provided in Price effective date 
    with US Time. So This error can be solved by waiting till US time and "Price Effective 
    date" mathches. 
        So Either Provide US date/time as Price Effective date or wait for given 
    Price Effective date reaches US date.

Comment: It can be solved by changing the computer's timezone to US. Not really clever, Apple.

Answer (score 1):

I kept getting this error no matter what dates I entered. Finally read the [docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/LanguagesUtilities/Conceptual/iTunesConnectInAppPurchase_Guide/Chapters/WorkingWithYourProductsMetadata.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40013727-CH7-SW1) and tried:

Price Tier Effective Date: Now

Price Tier End Date: None

And all my products uploaded successfully.